# Run Rscript and pass it a string instead of a file

Tags: python, r, escaping

I am calling `Rscript` inside python. The normal call is straightforward

```
retcode = subprocess.call("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla filename.r", shell=True)
```

But I have the challenge of dealing with an HDFS R file, so I need to read the file out first and compose the entire code as one string. When I try to use `eval`:

```
retcode = subprocess.call("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla -e \"eval(parse(text=" + rcode_string + "))\"", shell=True)
```

Either with or without `parse`, the quote marks in the R code cause problems. It would be impossible to escape every single quote inside the R code. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: why not write the script to a temp file and execute it?

Comment: Hi, I thought about that. it would have been my ugly back up solution. I fixed this with an R wrapper which does not include any single quotes. This wrapper calls the final complicated script once in the R world. In the python world, I used a combination of triple quotes, single and double quotes to eliminate all conflicts. I wish there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can send code directly to `Rscript` via standard input. According to [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/Rscript), if you specify `-` as the filename it will read from standard input.

From Python passing to standard input looks like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
r = Popen("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla -", stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
r.communicate(input=rcode_string)
```